# Create DataFrame / Dataset using Header and Data in two different directories

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the input file as CSV. Here I get two directories, first directory will have one file with header record and second directory will have data files. Here, I want to create a Dataframe/Dataset.

One way I can do is creating case class and split the data files by delimiter and attached the schema and create dataFrame.

What I am looking is read Header file and data file and create dataFrame. I saw a solution using databricks but my organization has restriction to use the databricks and below is the code which I come across. Can one you help me the solution without using databricks.

```
val headersDF = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("path to headers.csv")

val schema = headersDF.schema

val dataDF = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("path to data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
 val schema=spark
.read
.format("csv")
.option("header","true")
.option("delimiter",",")
.load("C:\\spark\\programs\\empheaders.csv")
.schema

val data=spark
.read
.format("csv")
.schema(schema)
.option("delimiter",",")
.load("C:\\spark\\programs\\empdata.csv")
```

Comment: I tried the way you given. I am able to get the schema correctly from the first statement. The second one when I display after loading, it did not split by delimiter (I used "\t").  Each record is consider as one column, so the split is not working on the data correctly. I put my statement here and let me know if I did anything wrong.                                     Continued the statement in the next comment due to space issue.

Comment: val csvDFHead = sparkFile
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", true)
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .load(s"$Hpath")
      .schema
 
 

    val csvDF = sparkFile
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("delimeter", "\t")
      .schema(csvDFHead)
      .load(s"$Dpath")

Answer (score 0):

Because in your header CSV file you don't have any data there is no point in inferring the schema out of it.
So just get the field names by reading it.

```
val headerRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Name,Age,Sal"))) //Assume this line is in your Header CSV
val header = headerRDD.flatMap(_.split(",")).collect

//headerRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[70] at parallelize at command-2903591155643047:1
//header: Array[String] = Array(Name, Age, Sal)
```

Then read the data CSV file.
Either map each line to a case class or a tuple. Convert the data to a DataFrame by passing the header array.

```
val dataRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Tom,22,500000"),("Rick,40,1000000"))) //Assume these lines are in your data CSV file
val data = dataRdd.map(_.split(",")).map(x => (x(0),x(1).toInt,x(2).toDouble)).toDF(header: _*)

//dataRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[72] at parallelize at command-2903591155643048:1
//data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, Age: int ... 1 more field]
```

Result:

```
data.show() 
+----+---+---------+
|Name|Age|      Sal|
+----+---+---------+
| Tom| 22| 500000.0|
|Rick| 40|1000000.0|
+----+---+---------+
```